# 1 pixel wide between amber and green color

Tags: android, layout

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5l3Hi.jpg)I need to display only 1dp wide between Amber and green  in Android layout.

```
this is drawable xml file
```

I need to display only 1dp wide between Amber and green

```
this is drawable xml file
```

```
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners
                android:radius="0dip" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#ffA8C647"
                android:endColor="#ffA8C647"
                android:angle="90" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners
                    android:radius="0dip" />
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="#FFF"
                    android:endColor="#FFF"
                    android:angle="90" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners
                    android:radius="0dip" />
                <gradient
                    [android:startColor="#ffFF9601"
                    android:centerColor="#ffFF9601"
                    android:centerY="0.50"
                    android:endColor="#ffFF9601"
                    android:angle="270" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>][1]
```

I need to display only 1dp wide between Amber and green in layout

Comment: where are you using this drawable file ?

Comment: <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/test"
          
            android:progressDrawable="this is the drawable file"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
         
            android:max="100"
            android:secondaryProgress="0"
            android:progress="100" />